# Login using Javascript and REST

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I made a REST service, which will return a String "hej" if the log in is true.
I have tested in Java with a rest client and it works fine, but pretty new to javascript and need some help.

I'm using this function

```
function UserAction() {
console.log(User());
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Footballmanagerrestservice/webresources/login");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("login", User());
    xhttp.responseType = 'text';

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log('DONE', xhttp.readyState); 
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {;
        // handle response
        var response = xhttp.responseText;
        console.log(response);
        if (response == "hej") {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
};

// send the request *after* the callback is defined 
xhttp.send();
return false;
}

function User() {
username = document.getElementById("username").toString();
username = document.getElementById("password").toString();
var UserAndPass = "?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
return UserAndPass;
}
```

I show you the client i have i Java, maybe you can see why it's not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

  String root="http://localhost:8080/Footballmanagerrestservice/webresources/";


String functionPath="login";

String parameters="?username=s153518&password=holger";
Response res = client.target(root+functionPath+parameters)
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
String svar = res.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(svar);
}
```

Comment: You specify username and password in java, but login in javascript. What is User() ?

Comment: @AhmadWabbi User function is added :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first part of the code looks ok, the following instead must be handled inside a function because is intrinsically asynchronous

```
var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
console.log(response);
if (response.toString() == "hej") {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
    window.location.href = url
}
return false;
```

doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

essentially you're trying to handle the response as a syncrhonous call, but it's not, the response it's not immediatly avaiable, for this reason you have to register a callback (from the doc must be attached to the field `onreadystatechange`) that will be triggered by javascript as soon as the server response is available.

try to change it like so:

```
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
      // handle response
      var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      console.log(response);
      if (response.toString() == "hej") {
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
        window.location.href = url
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.send();
```

Comment: I'm still at the learning state and pretty new to JavaScript and REST. Can you explain in deeper what you mean?

Comment: Okay, I tried changing the code and I'm getting 2 errors.
GET http://localhost:8080/Footballmanagerrestservice/webresources/ 404 (Not Found)
You have any idea why it cant find it? The java client works fine.

And the next error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.UserAction.xhttp.onreadystatechange (load_user.js:18)
    at UserAction (load_user.js:28)
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (index_1_1.html:51)

Comment: fix this method: xhttp.open(), remove the false at the end. regarding the problems you're having  try debugging, put a breakpoint inside the callback and check if you have the response

Comment: Thank you Karim!
It's almost working now.

One last question, do you have any idea why the REST service get null for both username and password?

Comment: no problem:). check the dom and be sure you have defined both elements with id="username" and id="password"

Comment: It works perfectly now, i had to change the xhttp.open, to xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Footballmanagerrestservice/webresources/login?username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
and remove xhttp.serRequestHeader.

Comment: glad you fixed it. if you think this answer helped you resolveing your errors please mark it as correct.